# Big-O notation when the function has negative value

Tags: function, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, discrete-mathematics, proof

i need to proof that 2n^2 - 2n -7 = O(n^2),   when the n is 1 or two i got negative value of f(n). i am not sure does the way i proof Big-O is correct.Your help and advice is highly appreciated.

```
              f(n) = 2n^2 - 2n -7 = O(n^2)  if c=2;
              n=1->2(1)^2 - 2(1) -7 = -7 <= 2*(1)^2
              n=2->2(2)^2 - 2(2) -7 = -3 <= 2*(2)^2
              n=3->2(3)^2 - 2(3) -7 = 14 <= 2*(3)^2
```

Comment: If you want to prove something, review the definition. Your attempt does not use the definition of O(n^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of Big-Oh has more to do with asymptotic behavior than local behavior. If your function went negative for increasing values of `n`, say it oscillated, there might be more of a concern. For this function, though, there is no problem: you are free to consider the function for all values greater than some `n0` which you alone are allowed to choose. So, if the function going negative early on bothers you, write your proof such that those numbers aren't used. For example:

Base case: for `n = 3`, `f(n) = 2*3*3 - 2*3 - 7 = 18 - 6 - 7 = 5 <= 9 * c = c * 3 * 3 = c * n^2`. This is true provided that `c >= 5/9`.

Induction hypothesis: assume `f(n) <= c * n^2` for all n starting at 3 up through `k`.

Induction step: we must show that `f(k+1) <= c * (k+1)^2`. We have `f(k+1) = 2(k+1)^2 - 2(k+1) - 7 = 2k^2+4k+2 - 2k - 2 - 7 = 2k^2 + 2k - 7 < 2k^2 + 4k < 2k^2 + 4k + 2 = 2(k^2 + 2k + 1) = 2(k+1)^2`, so the choice `c = 2` works here.

In hindsight, it should be obvious that `2n^2 - 2n - 7` is always less than `2n^2` for positive increasing `n`.